# Determine all the analytic functions on $\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=f(-z)$; $\forall $ $z$ in $ \Bbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

find all the analytic functions on $\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=f(-z)$; $\forall $ $z$ in $ \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: gaurav: Could you please frame your question in the form of a question, rather than as a command?  Also, others are more likely to answer your question if you explain some of your own thoughts. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$ can be expressed as a convergent power series in $z$.

Comment: I got it.all the even polynomials over ${C}$ are the answers .isn't it?

Comment: Not just polynomials. For example $f(z) = \cos(z)$, but you are on the right track with even powers.